# Refreshing MatTableDataSource causes the selection of the row to be removed

Tags: angular

I have angular material table with single selection:

`selection = new SelectionModel<Schedule>(false, []);`

```
this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(this.schedules);
```

My problem is that when I do re-assignment (after modifying selected `Schedule`) to `this.dataSource` (`MatTableDataSourcetype`) it causes the selected table row (`light-blue background`) to be removed (changed back to `white background`)
How can I retain the selection after assignment?